# Add a node in a single linked list

Tags: java, algorithm

Good evening

I'm trying to implement a single linked list by myself and I've run into an issue when I want to create a search method. Evidently when you want to search for a node (which will be used to insert a node at a certain place) you will have to evaluate some values to see if you reached the right spot. Considering my nodes only have a data field as a identifier, I don't see any other way than using that. However, since the data field isn't unique there might be multiple nodes eligible.

Consider the following list: 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 1, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2.
When I want to add a node somewhere in the list (say: After the node with value 8) he will go trough the list and add the new node after the first occurrence of '8'. What should I do if I wanted to insert it after the 2nd 8?

Is this even possible with a Single Linked List?

Other than that I'd like to have some feedback on my 'removeLast()' method which doesn't seem to do what I want it to do (remove the last node from the list). I am aware my code isn't supposed to work if the list has only 1 value, I'll look into that as soon as the general code of removing the last node works.

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Vannevelj/Exercises/tree/master/Exercises/src).

Edited with code:

```
 public class SingleLinkedList {

 public void deleteLast() {
    if (lastNode != null) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            Node nextNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
            Node nextNextNode = nextNode.getNextNode();

            if (nextNextNode == null) {
                nextNextNode = null;
                lastNode = nextNode;
            }
        }
        listSize--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is possible, but is what is the semantic of your method? Insert a number after all occurrences of some number?

Comment: It is here as well. I have no idea why I said evening.

Comment: Please put the code inside your question.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I'd like to add a node at a specified place. The problem is that I don't know how to specify this particular spot, considering the only thing that defines a node is their data, which isn't unique.
I was considering using their 'index' in the list, but if I need an index, why would I use a list instead of an array?

Comment: If it's evening, you'd be about the same time zone as...Tokyo.

Comment: You should minimize the problem to the minimal compileable code that demonstrate the issue, and not put the entire project in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it can be done - you need to keep track of the number of objects you have passed in the way, and after you have passed `n` objects equals to the seeked one - insert the new data:

```
public void addAfterNth(Object data,Object o, int n) { 
    Node curr = firstNode;
    while (curr != null) { 
        if (curr.data.equals(o)) n--;
        if (n == 0) { 
            Node newNode = new Node(data,curr.nextNode);
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        }
        curr = curr.getNextNode();
    }
}
```

In here you insert a new node with the data denoted in the parameter `data` after the `n`th encounter of a node with data equals to `o`.

Running with:

```
SingleLinkedList list = new SingleLinkedList();
list.addLast(5);
list.addLast(7);
list.addLast(2);
list.addLast(8);
list.addLast(3);
list.addLast(1);
list.addLast(6);
list.addLast(5);
list.addLast(8);
list.addLast(4);
list.addLast(2);
list.drawList();
list.addAfterNth(999,8, 2);
System.out.println("");
list.drawList();
```

yields (as expected):

```
5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 1, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 
5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 1, 6, 5, 8, 999, 4, 2,
```

Comment: You are welcome. Note that if number of elements requested is smaller then `n` (for example if you would insert `n==4` in the above example), it will be silently ignored - which is probably not a good thing. You should probably throw an exception or return `false` in these cases (change the signature to return `boolean` instead of `void).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code for deleting the last code of a LL. The above answer correctly answers your question of inserting at a specific position.

```
if (START == NULL){
    Print: Linked-List is empty.
}
else{
    PTR = START, PREV = START
    while (PTR->LINK != NULL)enter code here
        PREV = PTR //Assign PTR to PREV
    PTR = PTR->LINK //Move PTR to next node

    ITEM = PTR->INFO //Assign INFO of last node to ITEM
    If (START->LINK == NULL) Then //If only one node is left
        START = NULL //Assign NULL to START
    Else
        PREV->LINK = NULL //Assign NULL to link field of second last node

    Delete PTR
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this! I got it working on my own with the following code:

http://pastebin.com/QkE3EQpx